# how to compare two list ,object instances in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Say if I have:

```
list1 = [1,6]
list2 = [1]
```

I want to do something if list values match!

Compare it and do stuff after that

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Mmm, like this?

```
if list1 == list2: # compare lists for equality
    doStuff()      # if lists are equal, do stuff after that
```

Of course, you need to clarify what do you mean by "if lists values match". The above will check to see if both lists have the same elements, in the same position - that is, if they're *equal*.

**EDIT:**

The question is not clear, let's see some possible interpretations. To check if all elements in `list1` are also in `list2` do this:

```
if all(x in list2 for x in list1):
    doStuff()
```

Or to do something with each element in `list1` that also belongs in `list2`, do this:

```
for e in set(list1) & set(list2):
    doStuff(e)
```

Comment: No, in Python this checks if both lists are _equal_: same elements, in same position. It's in Java where this would mean an identity comparison, in Python it's an equality comparison

Comment: Actualu    i  want  to  find  whether   each  element  in  list  1  is  there  on  list 2  or not  if  it  exists  then  do something  with  the  match

Comment: @user2481309 Please edit your question with some examples.

Comment: I  want  to  check  whether  each  element  in  list  1  is  in  list  2  if   it  does  do  something

Comment: Then it's this one: `if all(x in list2 for x in list1)`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`any()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any):

```
>>> L1 = [1,6]
>>> L2 = [1]
>>> any(i in L1 for i in L2)
True
```

Pretty much, it loops through each item in `L2` and if any item in L2 is in `L1`, then it will return `True`.

If you want to see whether each item is in the other list, and print which ones are and which ones aren't:

```
>>> for i in L2:
...     if i in L1:
...             print i, "is in L1"
...     else:
...             doStuff(i)
```

Comment: That would ignore order of the lists.

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer What does order have to do with it?

Comment: it would say that ``[1,2,3]`` and ``[3,2,1]`` are equal.

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer It depends on what the OP's intention is. We don't know whether OP wants to know if an item is in another list or if both lists have the same elements.

Comment: I was about to write that, agreed.

Comment: Does  i    is  the one   which  shows  matched  element?

Comment: @user2481309 Err, could you please rephrase your sentence

Comment: What  does  i  shows  in  yr  answer  ? The  matched  element?

Comment: @user2481309 It prints what item from `L2` is in `L1`. If the item in `L2` is not in `L1`, then it will do stuff with the item.

Comment: Ok  should  i  use  it  in  development!

Comment: I  need  to  run  these  every  time  message  comes  from. Client  via  websocket  and   check  its   friends  is  online  and  compare  his  friends  list  vs   online  clients,is  this  the  right  approach?

Comment: @user2481309 If you just want to know whether the message appears in another list, then use `any()`. If you want to figure out which messages don't appear in the other list, use the for-loop

Answer (score 0):

Simple method, though not necessarily the most efficient (using [`all()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) instead of `any()`):

```
listsEqual = len(list1) == len(list2) and all(list1[i] == list2[i] for i in range(len(list1))
```